# How to make Visual Studio check if file content changed before building?

Tags: visual-studio, build-process

Visual Studio uses timestamps to determine whether file has changed or not before building it. However, in my case it is not sufficient as timestamps may change, but the content will remain the same. Is there a way to make Visual Studio check if file content changed (e.g. using MD5 hash) and only build if it did? Any add-in or built-in functionality?

System info: VS Team System 2008 Version 3.5 SP1, Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible.

[[source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/b46989d3-3005-4e1b-86ed-47ce05491d34/)]